# How to Encode JSON array in Doctrine?

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I convert an Array into JSON in Doctrine ?

**So far I have tried this.Here is my code:**

```
require_once ("../Users.php");
require_once("../../test/doctrine/cli-config.php");
require_once "../../test/doctrine/bootstrap.php";

            $user_list = array();

            $usersRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Users');

            $users = $usersRepository->findAll();  

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($users);

            foreach ($users as $user) 
            {
                $user_list[] = array('user_list'=>$user);   
            }


  json_encode($user_list)
```

**The print_r() section is returning me this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Users Object
        (
            [id:Users:private] => 1
            [lastName:Users:private] => User1
            [firstName:Users:private] => Test1
            [city:Users:private] => ABC
            [country:Users:private] => XYZ
            [email:Users:private] => user1@yahoo.com
        )

    [1] => Users Object
        (
            [id:Users:private] => 2
            [lastName:Users:private] => User2
            [firstName:Users:private] => Test1
            [city:Users:private] => ABC
            [country:Users:private] => XYZ
            [email:Users:private] => user2@yahoo.com
        )

)
[{"user_list":{}},{"user_list":{}}]
```

See the Json Response is Empty. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I recommand using [**JMS/Serializer**](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer) to export your entities

Comment: @Touki I am getting these errors
Undefined variable: serializer
Fatal error: Call to a member function serialize() on a non-object

Comment: Please, take time to [read the documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) correctly, and to [search for your error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/1607098) before asking. I'm pretty sure you didn't follow the installations steps which is why you are getting this error.

Comment: @Touki I did the same as they explained in Documention, but its still giving me these errors.

Comment: This is basically the lbrary is not installed properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have public properties in your entities... that's why you get an empty json.

I am using for this purpose [EntitySerializer](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php)

Usage for your case should be:

```
$eSerializer = new Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer($entityManager);
$result = $eSerializer->toArray($users);
```

but this is just a personal preference. 
You could an should use the standard [Serializer class of Symfony framework](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: Do i have to include this library somewhere?

Comment: Plus for some reason I could not use $em ,it gives me error, I use  $entityManager

Comment: I have installed that library but its giving me error Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\common\library\Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer.php on line 69

Comment: You must use `foreach ($users as $user) {$user_list[] = $eSerializer->toArray($user); }` and after that json_encode($user_list).

Comment: require_once "../../test/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/common/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php";

 
      $user_list = array();
  
    $usersRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Users');
    
    $users = $usersRepository->findAll();

    $eSerializer = new Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer($entityManager);

    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
     $user_list[] = $eSerializer->toArray($user); 
    }
    
    $result = $eSerializer->toArray($users);
    echo json_encode($result);

Comment: And I m Getting a warning : Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\common\library\Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer.php on line 69

Comment: require_once in Symfony2? remove $result = $eSerializer->toArray($users);  and then echo json_encode($user_list);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39812/discussion-between-code-hunter-and-udan)

Comment: It worked Thanks alot for the help :) 
Plus also tell me what to use instead of require_once in Doctrine2 ???